# opensslunable to load certificate22704:error:0906D06C:PEMroutines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:650:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Tags: openssl, keystore

I have converted the PEM to keystore.PKCS12 format. I just want to check the format is correct or not after the conversion but getting below error. I have tried with the below commands. Can anyone help me how to check the conversion/content format is correct or not ?

Commands:

**To convert to kesytore.pkcs12:**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -passout pass:changeit -out keystore.pkcs12 -in C:\sample\keystore.pem
```

**To convert to text format**

```
openssl x509 -text -in C:\DevCertificate\keystore.pkcs12 -passin pass:changeit

Error Details:
unable to load certificate
22704:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:650:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```